# when I start Spring project,the controller method will be called three times

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am using Spring 4.2.5. When I first run the Spring project and visit `localhost`, the mapped controller method will be called three times. After that, when I visit `localhost`, it is called only once.

If you do not understand what I mean, please comment, because my English is not very good.

```
public class AppWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {
                WebConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("utf-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[]{characterEncodingFilter};
    }

}
```

And my webconfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"kyzs.web"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
        return viewResolver;
    }
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(mainResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateResolver mainResolver() {
        TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private HttpLogin httpLogin;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(){
        System.out.println("home");   //print three times ,when first called.
        return "home";
    }

}
```

My pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

log

```
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:139 - Servlet 'dispatcher' configured successfully
[2016-05-10 02:59:04,136] Artifact KyZsBackend:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-05-10 02:59:04,136] Artifact KyZsBackend:war: Deploy took 4,901 milliseconds
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/]
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:301 - Looking up handler method for path /
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:308 - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String kyzs.web.HomeController.home()]
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'homeController'
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:947 - Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
home
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1240 - Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@2b57f853] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:998 - Successfully completed request
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/]
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:301 - Looking up handler method for path /
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:308 - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String kyzs.web.HomeController.home()]
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'homeController'
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:947 - Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
home
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1240 - Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@2b57f853] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2016-05-10 14:59:04 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:998 - Successfully completed request
2016-05-10 14:59:05 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/]
2016-05-10 14:59:05 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:301 - Looking up handler method for path /
2016-05-10 14:59:05 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:308 - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String kyzs.web.HomeController.home()]
2016-05-10 14:59:05 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'homeController'
2016-05-10 14:59:05 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:947 - Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
home
2016-05-10 14:59:05 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1240 - Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@2b57f853] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2016-05-10 14:59:05 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:998 - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Can you add some logs for `org.springframework.web` package with DEBUG level?

Comment: try to remove `configurer.enable();` in your Configuration. What happens now?

Comment: How did you deploy your app? Are you using IntelliJ and its run configurations with Tomcat?

Comment: yes.I ues IntelliJ and its run configurations with Tomcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's IntelliJ's `After Launch` feature that calling your web app three times. Nothing is wrong with your Spring Configurations. In order to fix this problem, just go to `Edit Configuration` in IntelliJ and un-check the `After Launch` check box:

[image]

Comment: you are  the hero.

Comment: I've spent 4 hours debugging this issue and it's from intellij!
Why the do this heck by calling it 3 times?
Anyway, you made my day man, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Checks your pom.xml, I think some dependency or parameter are called more times from there. For example, be sure this is configured properly. dispatcher-servlet should be called one time, either in your pom or in other configuration file.

Even so, can you try with this configuration.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-proyect</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>     

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>    

</project>
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("kyzs.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver(){
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();

        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB_INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

        return resolver;
    }

}
```

AppWebInitializer.java

```
public class AppWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Comment: I have no other configuration file.I post the `pom.xml`.Please help me to check

Comment: Ok, let me check. No errors or warning on console when you run it ?

Comment: Ok, can you check it. It's normally running and prints home once.